# How to return a desired datatype from a method in Scala particularly when the method has try/catch block in it?

Tags: scala

I declared a Scala method that returns a String by its definition. It has JDBC connection inside and I surrounded the lines in my method with try/catch block.

```
def getOutage(): String = {
    val con = new DbManager().getOutageDbConnection
    try {
      val statement:Statement = con.get.createStatement()
      val rs = statement.executeQuery("select status from outagetable where dbname='snowflake' and category='outage'")
      while (rs.next()) {
        if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
          "true"
        }
        else if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
          "false"
        }
      }
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        e.printStackTrace()
        e.toString
    } finally {
      con.get.close()
    }
  }
```

The problem I see is that the try/catch block is returning Unit which is conflicting with String I gave in the method definition. So went thru some documentation and followed suggestion to return a String from the catch clause as well which I did above. But I still see the same error message exactly at the line of catch statement.

[image]

Could anyone let me know how can I return a String from the method while using try/catch block and the scala way to do it.

Comment: Please do not use **Scala** as **Java**. There is nothing wrong with OOP or a little bit of imperativity. - But this code reflects **Java** with juts different syntax; you do not even accept the connection as a parameter. If that is the approach you want to follow, then **Kotlin** would be better since **Scala** would cause you more troubles.

Answer (score 1):

`while` expression is of type `Unit`. If you already decided to use dirty approach you have to assign returned values to some `var` and return that `var`:

```
      var result: String = _
      while (rs.next()) {
        if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
          result = "true"
        }
        else if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
          result = "false"
        }
      }
      result
```

Notice though, that your `while` might go through whole collection and not match anything, so `result` might be `null` in the end.

If you have 2.13 I would use `Using` to handle connection:

```
scala.util.Using(new DbManager().getOutageDbConnection) { con =>
  // code here
}
```

and unless you have a good reason to use `while` I would use tail recursion instead

```
@tailrec
def handleResult(): Option[String] = {
  if (rs.next()) {
    if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
      Some("true")
    }
    else if (rs.getString(1).equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
      Some("false")
    }
    else handleResult()
  }
  else None
}
```

Comment: I am using 2.13.